# Symfony 3 user repository in login listener

Tags: doctrine-orm, repository, listener, symfony

I'm willing to build listener for loginaction, to update login count and last login date to database when user logs in successfully.

I get user details successfully but can't access them and can't update database

src/AppBundle/Listener/SecurityListener.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
#use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class SecurityListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, EntityManager $doctrine)
    {

    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
    if ( $event->getAuthenticationToken()->isAuthenticated() ) {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
            var_dump($user->id);
    }

    /**
     * Update lastLogin and loginCount for user in database
     */

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($user->id);

        if( !$user )
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'User could not be found for id '. $user->id
            );
        }

        $user->setLastLogin(date());
        $user->setLoginCount($user->loginCount +1);
        $em->flush;


    }

}
```

error:

```
Error: Cannot access private property AppBundle\Entity\User::$id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities properties are usually private, but you can always use getter methods.

Please update your code similar to this example:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException(
    'User could not be found for id '. $user->getId()
);
```

You can also try method called `getID()`, if my example fails.

Comment: I have method getId() in user entity, tho it does not work, I get error `Notice: Undefined property: AppBundle\Entity\User::$getId`. I'm assuming that I have just small misunderstanding here or something...

Comment: Sorry, it works with $user->getId() .... I just had invisible character after that so it returned that error... Your answer fixed, so to get wanted data I had to use getter method